# Minecraft chunk loading 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a world in Minecraft (Hogwarts) and I want to have the great hall and my requirement is to have the celing changing via command blocks. I tried to do that, but the command block said "cannot place blocks outside the world". Is there a vanilla way to get around this or are we needing to wait for mods and put a chunk loader in those chunks.

Comment: There is indeed. Either build in spawn chunks, reset or relocate spawn chunks or convince the game the chunk is actively being used. The latter would require more explanation which I can't give atm but later if nobody else does so.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I did /setworldspawn and the chunks that I wanted are loaded all the time now. Feel free to add a way to keep them loaded (mainly for command block use) if I decide to change world spawn again.

Comment: I think keeping a chunk loaded is as simple as putting a hopper in an adjacent chuck pointing into the chunk you want to keep loaded.